# Adding events to multiple childNodes in a for() respecting index

Tags: javascript, events, for-loop, var

I need to implement a simple event and dom manipulation, but I can't use jQuery

So I am attaching the event to each single node using `for()`

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var mainList = document.getElementById('mainList');
    var mainNodes = document.querySelectorAll('#mainList > li');
    for (var i = 0; i < mainNodes.length; i++) { 
        var node = mainNodes[i]; 
        node.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var currentActive = document.querySelectorAll('.active');
           if(currentActive[0]) { // first item with class 'active'
                currentActive[0].className = '';
            }
            this.className = 'active';
        });
        var options = node.getElementsByTagName('li');
        for (var j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
            var option = options[j]; 
            option.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                switch(this.className){
                    case 'eliminar':
                        delete(mainList,node);
                        break;
                    case 'obrir':
                        open(mainList,node);
                        break;
                    case 'clonar':
                        clone(mainList,node);
                        break;
                }
                node.className = '';
            });    
        }
    }       
});
```

The problem here is that even that all elemnts have the event, its allways opened/cloned/deleted the last node,

Doesn't using `var node` applies only to the current node in the loop?

-fiddle-

http://jsfiddle.net/toniweb/Wx8Jf/34/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler will be triggered ***later***. When the loop finishes, the `node` is the last node. You need to create a **closure** to capture the current node. Something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < mainNodes.length; i++) { (function(node){
  //your code
  }(mainNodes[i]))
}
```

Try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < mainNodes.length; i++) { (function(node){
  //Your code
  node.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var currentActive = document.querySelectorAll('.active');
       if(currentActive[0]) { // first item with class 'active'
            currentActive[0].className = '';
        }
        this.className = 'active';
    });
    var options = node.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (var j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
        var option = options[j]; 
        option.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            switch(this.className){
                case 'eliminar':
                    delete(mainList,node);
                    break;
                case 'obrir':
                    open(mainList,node);
                    break;
                case 'clonar':
                    clone(mainList,node);
                    break;
            }
            node.className = '';
        });    
    }
}(mainNodes[i]))
}
```